# Script shell how to add x minutes to a given date?

Tags: bash, shell

I need to add 10 minutes to a given date :

```
givenDate = 2016-10-25 18:22:37
```

when executing :

```
newDate=$(date +'%Y-%m-%d %T' --date="$givenDate + 10 minutes")
echo $newDate
```

I get :

> 2016-10-25 00:10:00

instead of

> 2016-10-25 18:32:37

2nd question: How can I round the minutes number so I can get these results per exemple:

18:08 -> 18:10

18:32 -> 18:40

18:46 -> 18:50

18:55 -> 19:00

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for the first question drop the `+` like this:

```
date +'%Y-%m-%d %T' --date="$givenDate 10 minutes"
```

for the second question we have to extract the last digit of current minutes, then compute the number of minutes to add to make it round using modulo 5:

```
givenDate="2016-10-25 18:22:37"

minute=$(echo $givenDate | sed 's/.*\([0-9]\):..$/\1/')
rounder=$((5 - minute % 5))
date +'%Y-%m-%d %T' --date="$givenDate $rounder minutes"
```

note that the seconds haven't been taken into account

Comment: Thank you @Jean-François you're my hero ! :)